# Could my object use static methods? Anything I need to do to make the code better?

Tags: php, object-oriented, static

With the Zend coding convention in the back of my mind, [I have set this up](https://github.com/Michal-sk/TargetSMS).

It lets you communicate with the API of the vendor `TargetSMS`. They allow you to bill customers trough SMS. For now I've only spent time on the `NonSubscription` option.

I would just like to know if it's ok, or what could be better.  I am mostly interested in knowing if the `TargetSms` object could use static methods.  For example, I think the `isAllowedIp` method could be static, since I would like to use it even if the object is not initiated (I was told that's the idea behind static methods).

**TargetSMS object**

```
<?php
/**
* TargetSMS object with TargetSMS related methods.
*/

namespace TargetPay\Sms;

class TargetSms
{
    /**
* The allowed IP of TargetSms.
* @var array
*/
    protected $_targetSmsIp = array('89.184.168.65');

    /**
* The ok response code for TargetSMS.
* @var number
*/
    protected $_responseCode = 45000;

    /**
* Check if the request is comming from TargetSMS.
* @param string $ip
* @return boolean
*/
    public function isAllowedIp($ip = '')
    {
        if (in_array($ip, $this->_targetSmsIp)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
* Get the TargetSMS required responsecode.
* @return number
*/
    public function getResponseCode()
    {
        return $this->_responseCode;
    }

    /**
* Add a new allowed ip address to the array with allowed ip addresses.
* @param string $ip
*/
    public function addAllowedIp($ip = '')
    {
        $this->_targetSmsIp[] = $ip;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to make `isAllowdIp` static (and there's nothing wrong with that, per se), you -indeed- don't need an instance of your class to call that method. But owing to there being no instance, you won't have access to any non-static properties of your class, either.
To get around that, you'd have to change:

```
protected $_targetSmsIp = array('89.184.168.65');
```

To

```
protected static $_targetSmsIp = array('89.184.168.65');
```

And change these method, too:

```
public static function isAllowedIp($ip)
{//don't check empty strings, they're always invalid ips!
    return !!in_array($ip, self::$_targetSmsIp);
}
public static function addAllowedIp($ip)
{//don't allow '' defaults! adding empty strings aren't valid ips
    if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
    {//check what you're adding to the OK-list!
        throw new InvalidArgumentException($ip. ' is not a valid IP');
    }
    self::$_targetSmsIp[] = $ip;
}
```

This, by itself isn't code that makes my eyes water, but it doesn't exactly sit well with me, either: It's hard to tell what the actual task of your class is: validate IP's/data? Is it the API connection layer?
I gather it's the latter. In which case, I'd define my methods to *only* accept objects of a given type. This object is where you can filter, check and validate all input... For example, the `IpObject`:

```
class IpObject
{
    private $ip = null;
    private static $valideIps = array();
    public function __construct($ip = null)
    {
        if ($ip)
        {
            $this->setIp($ip);
        }
    }
    public function getIp()
    {
        return $this->ip;
    }
    public function setIp($ip)
    {
        if (!filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) || !in_array($ip, self::$validIps))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException($ip.' is not valid');
        }
        $this->ip = $ip;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The major problem with your creating statics here is that, by changeing the allowed IP's for one instance, you're changing the allowed IP's accross the board: you can't black-list or OK ip's for instances of your object individually, so after a while it'll get quite tricky to work out which IP's are allowed and which aren't.

All in all, an array in this object won't add *too* much overhead... not that you notice, and it will make life easier when testing/debugging.
Instead of using statics. having an instance at the ready is 99.99% of times the better option.